# Confusion in Combining 4 Functions

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

please bear with me if my codes are messy or bulky, I am a real beginner which started programming a month ago with no background at all. I now have 4 functions created `searchComByAuthor();`, `searchComByStartDate();`, `searchComByEndDate();` and `searchComByKeywords();`. But the problem is, I don't know how to combine them and make them like filters. User can choose to fill up any textboxes and when the user clicks on "Analyse" button, the combined function will do the work. Now they are all working separately, I only call the functions one by one to test out if they work or not.

Screenshot:

[image: Filters]

`searchComByAuthor`:

```
private void searchComByAuthor()
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

            string docPath = fileName;

            xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {

                XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement)node;

                string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;

                if (itemAuthor.ToLower() == txtComAuthor.Text.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemXMLFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                    richComByTemplate.AppendText("SYMBOL: " + itemXMLFile + "\nAUTHOR: " + itemAuthor + "\nDATE: " + itemDate +
                                                "\nTITLE: " + itemTitle + "\nDESCRIPTION: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");

                }
                //else
                //{
                //    richComResults.AppendText("There is no author " + txtComAuthor.Text.ToString().ToLower() + ". Please ensure you are using a correct author name.");
                //}
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    int pointer = 0;
    int index = 0;
    string keyword = txtComAuthor.Text;
    string shadow = richComByTemplate.Text.ToLower();

    while (true)
    {
        //Searching in the copy/shadow
        index = shadow.IndexOf(keyword, pointer);
        //if keyword not found then the loop will break
        if ((index == -1) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword)))
        {
            break;
        }
        richComByTemplate.Select(index, keyword.Length);
        richComByTemplate.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        richComByTemplate.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(richComByTemplate.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        pointer = index + keyword.Length;
    }
}
```

`searchComByStartDate`:

```
private void searchComByStartDate()
{

    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

        string docPath = fileName;

        xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {

            XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement)node;

            string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            if (DateTime.Parse(itemDate) >= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider))
            {
                string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;
                string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;
                string itemXMLFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                richComByTemplate.AppendText("SYMBOL: " + itemXMLFile + "\nAUTHOR: " + itemAuthor + "\nDATE: " + itemDate + 
                                            "\nTITLE: " + itemTitle + "\nDESCRIPTION: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`searchComByEndDate`:

```
private void searchComByEndDate()
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

        string docPath = fileName;

        xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {

            XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement)node;

            string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            if (DateTime.Parse(itemDate) <= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider))
            {
                string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;
                string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;
                string itemXMLFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                richComByTemplate.AppendText("SYMBOL: " + itemXMLFile + "\nAUTHOR: " + itemAuthor + "\nDATE: " + itemDate + 
                                            "\nTITLE: " + itemTitle + "\nDESCRIPTION: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`searchComByKeywords`:

```
private void searchComByKeywords()
{
    List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>();
    boxes.Add(txtComKeyword1);
    boxes.Add(txtComKeyword2);
    boxes.Add(txtComKeyword3);
    boxes.Add(txtComKeyword4);

    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

            string docPath = fileName;

            xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement)node;

                string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;

                if (txtComKeyword1.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()) ||
                    txtComKeyword2.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword2.Text.ToLower()) ||
                    txtComKeyword3.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword3.Text.ToLower()) ||
                    txtComKeyword4.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword4.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemXMLFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                    richComByTemplate.AppendText("SYMBOL: " + itemXMLFile + "\nAUTHOR: " + itemAuthor + "\nDATE: " + itemDate + 
                                                "\nTITLE: " + itemTitle + "\nDESCRIPTION: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    foreach (TextBox box in boxes)
    {
        int pointer = 0;
        int index = 0;
        string keyword = box.Text;
        string shadow = richComByTemplate.Text.ToLower();

        while (true)
        {
            //Searching in the copy/shadow
            index = shadow.IndexOf(keyword, pointer);
            //if keyword not found then the loop will break
            if ((index == -1) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword)))
            {
                break;
            }
            //Customising the original data
            richComByTemplate.Select(index, keyword.Length);
            richComByTemplate.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            richComByTemplate.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(richComByTemplate.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            pointer = index + keyword.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a very significant amount of repeated code in your functions.

You can achieve your goal while simplifying your code by combining your four functions into a single function.  Give that single function a parameter that is a list of conditions that must be met in order to include a given record (assuming *all* conditions must apply to select the record).

In your case it looks like you desire a straight match on whatever is entered in one or more text fields.  Pass in the values of those text fields to your new, combined method (so that you can separate your logic from your UI) and, for each value that has a non-null, non-blank value, apply the appropriate logic test.  If Author and StartDate are passed in, apply the logic that is relevant to both Author and StartDate.  If both tests pass, include that record.

In order to "include that record", rather than doing what the code is currently doing:

```
richComByTemplate.AppendText(...)
```

you may wish to return a list of results and have the caller do the text appending (again, to separate your user interface from your search logic).

Comment: Hi Eric, my aim is to put them all into one function. When you say about "condition", does it means like "if statement"? or like "&&" and "||"?

Comment: There are several ways that you could do it.  In your case I suspect that combining conditions with && is that you're after `if (matchesConditionA && matchesConditionB) ...`

Comment: The end result will be cleaner and easier to maintain.  Any time you find yourself copying code for use in multiple functions, think about how to instead write a single function that gets an extra parameter or two instead.